# Installing a specific iOS on a new iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I've just bought a new 3rd Gen iPad as a gift.  I assume it comes with iOs 5.1 installed on it.  I want to install iOS 5.1.1 on it as I'd rather not use the Maps app provided in iOS 6.  I know that iTunes will only offer the latest version of iOS (6.0.1 at this time.)

How can I download and install iOS 5.1.1 to a new iPad?  I am not willing to jailbreak it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of information covering this exact topic in a question that I asked a while back:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65952/how-to-upgrade-iphone-3gs-to-ios-5-now-that-ios-6-is-out

The accepted answer provided me with this link: http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! And after all that, it turns out it came with 5.1.1 preinstalled anyway.